# SetBackgroundColor affects multiple list items

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, listitem

I'm developing a kiosk application (where certain applications are available). I made a listview which displays all application installed on the phone. In this list i want the user to select the application that are allowed to be used in the kiosk. If the user selects a row (which displays 1 application) it needs to change color and be put in a separate list (allowedAppList).

The strange thing is that when the user presses on a list item, the color changes correctly. But it will change also change the color of every 8th item below it.

I also log (see code) when a list item gets pressed, it only changes the allowance of the list item clicked, not every 8th item below.

Please help me

//I added just the code for clicking an list item

```
private void addClickListener(){
    allowedApps = new ArrayList<AppDetail>();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        boolean isAllowed;

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos,
                                long id) {

            isAllowed = apps.get(pos).allowed;
            if (isAllowed == false){
                apps.get(pos).allowed = true;
                Log.i("ALLOWED", apps.get(pos).name.toString());
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);

            }else if (isAllowed == true) {
                apps.get(pos).allowed = false;
                Log.i("NOT ALLOWED", apps.get(pos).name.toString());
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);

            }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**
Adapter code (where i load the apps installed)

```
private PackageManager manager;
private List<AppDetail> apps;
private void loadApps(){
    manager = getPackageManager();
    apps = new ArrayList<AppDetail>();

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = manager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo ri:availableActivities){
            AppDetail app = new AppDetail();
            app.label = ri.loadLabel(manager);
            app.name = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
            app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(manager);
            app.allowed = false;
            apps.add(app);
    }
    Log.i("applist", apps.toString());
}

private ListView list;
private void loadListView(){
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.apps_list);

    ArrayAdapter<AppDetail> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AppDetail>(this,
            R.layout.list_item,
            apps) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            ImageView appIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_icon);
            appIcon.setImageDrawable(apps.get(position).icon);

            TextView appLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_label);
            appLabel.setText(apps.get(position).label);

            TextView appName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_name);
            appName.setText(apps.get(position).name);

            if (apps.get(position).allowed == true){
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    };

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Please post your adapter code, that's likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: I think that the error is that you are using a Viewholder but you are not setting the tag for the view clicked, but post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the row views in a ListView get recycled. Therefore a solution would be to set a boolean attribute on the AppDetail object behind that row to indicate that it has been clicked, and set the background color in your Adapter's getView() function.
The relevant code would look something like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos,
                            long id) {
    [...]
    ((AppDetail) av.getAdapter().getItem(pos)).setClicked(true);
    [...]
}
```

And in your adapter

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    [...]
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(apps.getPosition(position).isClicked() ? R.color.green : R.color.white));
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I know what I've been doing wrong. I cant get the position from a item in onItemClick.

Comment: I think you can, isn't it the third parameter?

Comment: My bad, made a typo! Thanks